# Linux: How do I headlessly install an old version of VLC?

Tags: linux, installation, vlc, apt-get, headless

I need to install an old version of VLC from the command line (can't use a browser to download anything). I know it sounds weird, but the specific version of VLC doesn't matter as long as it isn't the most up to date.

EDIT

Based on the suggestion below I tried downloading and installing the .deb file but when I ran "apt-get install -f" after installing it, VLC was automatically updated to the newest version.

I tried again and put a hold on VLC (sudo apt-mark hold vlc), but that caused "apt-get install" to fail:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
vlc : Depends: ttf-freefont
   Depends: vlc-nox (= 1.1.9-1ubuntu1) but it is not installed
   Depends: libavcodec52 (>= 4:0.6-1~) but it is not installable or
            libavcodec-extra-52 (>= 4:0.6-1~) but it is not installable
   Depends: libavutil50 (>= 4:0.6-1~) but it is not installable or
            libavutil-extra-50 (>= 4:0.6-1~) but it is not installable
   Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx but it is not installed or
            libgl1
   Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but it is not installed
   Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not installed
   Depends: libsdl-image1.2 (>= 1.2.10) but it is not installed
   Depends: libtar
   Depends: libva-x11-1 but it is not installed
   Depends: libva1 but it is not installed
   Depends: libvlccore4 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
   Depends: libx11-xcb1 but it is not installed
   Depends: libxcb-keysyms1 (>= 0.3.6) but it is not installed
   Depends: libxcb-randr0 (>= 1.1) but it is not installed
   Depends: libxcb-xv0 (>= 1.2) but it is not installed
   Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 1.1.9-1ubuntu1) but it is not installed
   Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse (= 1.1.9-1ubuntu1) but it is not installable
   Recommends: xdg-utils but it is not installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get

Comment: apt-cache showpkg vlc does not list any older versions, so I don't think apt-get can help

Answer (score -2):

You can find the VLC 1.1.9 deb here:

32 bit - http://launchpadlibrarian.net/69370596/vlc_1.1.9-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
64 bit - http://launchpadlibrarian.net/69370658/vlc_1.1.9-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
You should consider locking the vlc package to prevent it from getting updated accidentally again.

How to prevent updating of a specific package?